# Show data from database table in tabular format by using row and column index

Tags: php, html, sql, postgresql

I have postgre sql database table in following format

```
Row_no  Col_no  Name
1        1      Test
1        2      Result
1        3      Observation
2        1      abc
2        2      Result1
2        3      observation1
```

And I want to show data in html table in following format

```
Test    Result     Observation
abc     Result1    observation1
```

So can any one suggest me how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method :**

1. create an array of output
2. select each row from your table
3. store them into output array by row and column index

   **like :**

   `$ARR_OUPUT[$row_no][$col_no] = $name;`
4. Now you can print them into a html table

   **like :**

   ```
   echo '<table>';
   foreach($ARR_OUTPUT as $key=>arr_temp)
   {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach($arr_temp as $name)
        {
             echo '<td>'.$name.'</td>';
        }
         echo '</tr>';
   } 
   echo '<table>';
   ```

your array will be look like this

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => Test
            [2] => Result
            [3] => Observation
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => abc
            [2] => Result1
            [3] => Observation1
        )

)
```

Answer (score -2):

Try below code

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Result</th>
            <th>Observation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
        $sql=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * from Name");
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
        {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Test'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Result'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['Observation'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php   }?>

    </tbody>

</table>
```